# Ubuntu ZFS - /boot/efi/grub mounted at /boot/grub in fstab - normal?

Tags: grub2, uefi, startup, bootloader, zfs

I'm noticing a "new" line in `fstab` I've never noticed before, and I'm wondering if it has to do with this installation being on ZFS

AFAICR `/boot/grub` has always existed independent of the `efi` partition, but in the case of this new installation, it lives on `/dev/nvme0n1p1` (the `efi` partition) in `/grub` and then is bind mounted to `/boot/grub`

Here's the exact line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=B045-5C3B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
/boot/efi/grub  /boot/grub  none    defaults,bind   0   0
```

(`efi` mountpoint added for context)

Questions:

Is this normal behavior, and I just haven't noticed it before?

If this is not typical of "regular" Ubuntu installations, is there some reason Ubuntu on ZFS needs `grub.cfg` (et. al.) to be available in the `efi` partition during startup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's the way the ZFS-root installer works. This makes GRUB's files accessible outside of ZFS, where it's probably easier to save menu state during boot.

My system (Ubuntu Studio) was the same:  Grub's binaries and configs are installed in /grub of the EFI partition.  Then a bind mount is declared from /boot/efi/grub to /boot/grub in fstab.